# Batch file to scheduled a task which starts a program when a USB is plugged in

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I create a batch file that creates a scheduled task (schtask) which starts a program when a USB or any other USB based storage is plugged in and accessible for usage?

Comment: Does [this do what you want](https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device)?